# Can std::optional::has_value() be made thread safe without an additional atomic_bool by using atomic_thread_fence?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization

I have an `optional<T>` that is populated exactly once, by a single thread “eventually” - after it does some calculation, IO, etc. There are many readers that call `has_value()` and if true, process the `T` value.  I don't need to use a mutex and a lock for this as it can only be set once, so I only need an `atomic_bool`.  But this seems wasteful<sup>1</sup> - after all, `std::optional` uses an extra `bool` to store if there's a value.  I could re-implement `optional` but make that `bool` atomic, but that's a pretty gross solution.

Simplified example showing an atomic version of a set-once/never reset atomic optional:
https://godbolt.org/z/YTaf878rK

```
template <typename T>
struct atomic_optional
{
    void set(T&& t)
    {
        opt = std::move(t);
        // must set after setting the value so it synchronizes with
        // another thread calling has_value() in the correct order
        isSet = true;
    }

    // must call before get() or contract broken
    bool has_value()
    {
        // if this is not atomic, there is no guarantee that all threads
        // can see that opt.has_value() has changed
        return isSet;
    }

    // can only call IFF has_value() returns true
    const T& get()
    {
        return *opt;
    }

    std::optional<T> opt {};
    std::atomic_bool isSet {false};
};
```

Can I use `std::atomic_thread_fence` for this instead of an `atomic_bool`?  E.g. fence instead of setting `isSet` to true, as well as fence in `has_value()` before calling `opt.has_value()`.  The [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence) say that you can synchronize around 2 fences for non-atomic operations, but it also specifically mentions an atomic object (which I don't have here). If fences will work as a solution here, using `memory_order_seq_cst` on both fences is correct, right?  If a bit slower on some architectures - acquire and release semantics are incredibly nuanced, easily broken with code churn, and hard to reproduce (especially so [impossibly so?] on x86/x86-64).

Fence version - is this correct?  Is there some other utility that I can use here that's a better fit?
https://godbolt.org/z/baeacMhf5

```
template <typename T>
struct atomic_optional
{
    void set(T&& t)
    {
        opt = std::move(t);
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst); // memory_order_release?
    }

    bool has_value()
    {
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst); // memory_order_acquire?
        return opt.has_value();
        // return value is immediately out of date if false and callers are expected
        // to understand this e.g. call again after doing some work
    }

    const T& get()
    {
        return *opt;
    }

    std::optional<T> opt {};
};
```

<sup>1</sup> For some definitions of wasteful - I realize this question is mostly academic.  In this case, it is most likely to be negligible as `optional` adds a `bool` and will then most likely require padding bytes.  The "extra" `atomic_bool` will fit in these padding bytes in a lot of cases, so it is unlikely to actually increase the size of the object.  For compound objects, of which this is a member, and which have other 1-byte or 2-byte members, it may save some bytes and actually prevent that object from needing padding.  Also consider [markable](https://github.com/akrzemi1/markable), which is an alternative to `optional` that does not add an extra `bool` but instead uses a sentinel value.

Comment: If it is set only once, can't you set it before starting your thread? Then you wouldn't need to worry about thread safety

Comment: Ah, thanks for the comment, I’ll update the question to clarify. In this case, the thread will *eventually* produce the value, after it does some calculation, IO, etc.  it doesn’t have the value right away - think of the optional as if it were a future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't turn code that is thread-unsafe due to the use of non-atomic variables into thread-safe code using a fence.

When the boolean flag is not atomic, there is potential for a *data race*, meaning that one thread sets the flag, another thread reads from the flag, and neither of those two operations happens before the other.

Often, a mutex is used to prevent data races in accesses to non-atomic variables. In effect, if two threads try to lock the mutex at the same time, one of them gets "slowed down" by being forced to wait until the other thread releases the mutex, at which point that thread is already done accessing the variable. Thus, one of the accesses happens before the other (depending on which thread manages to lock the mutex first).

The function of a fence is to introduce synchronization between threads under some circumstances. Informally, this means that a thread that reaches the fence, under some circumstances, is guaranteed to observe a state of the program such that all side effects caused by some other thread that reached a fence earlier have already completed.  (But fences only have synchronization effects when paired with atomic accesses, which are not present in your code.) However, under no circumstances does a thread that reaches a fence wait for some other thread to reach the fence first! So in your code, when one thread reaches the fence in `has_value`, it doesn't wait. And it goes on to call `opt.has_value()`; meanwhile, some other thread might have started writing to `opt`. So the data race is still there. Fences are not a replacement for mutexes.

You need a mutex or an atomic variable.

Comment: “ And it goes on to call opt.has_value(); meanwhile, some other thread might have started writing to opt.”

Ah, I see the problem, though it’s a little buried and perhaps implied. If I had the entire source of optional, I could do it with a fence. The problem comes from the fence’s position - it must go between optional’s setting of its value and optional’s set of its internal hasValue (and it must be in that order).  Otherwise it is possible for another thread to write hasValue and a reader to observe that and read from *value before the writer finishes writing the value.

Comment: @user450775 Unfortunately, no. A fence only introduces synchronization when paired with an atomic operation. See https://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.fences

Comment: I see, so in the docs (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence) under "Fence-fence synchronization," by "atomic object M" it means literally "an std::atomic<T> object M"?  As in, "atomic object" is not an abstraction around an object sandwiched between 2 fences.  Do you know why 2 fences cannot synchronize-with each other? Or if there's a term for this I can look up to find more?

Either way, thank you for your response! I'll accept your answer, but if you would be so kind as to edit it to refer to looking at these comments for more info I think it'd help others. Thanks!

Comment: @user450775 An atomic operation is either an operation on an atomic object, or an operation that accesses a non-atomic object through `std::atomic_ref`. But if you have a `std::atomic_ref` referring to an object then you have to make sure that all accesses to that object are only through `std::atomic_ref`.

Comment: @user450775 Fences do synchronize with other fences, but only when paired with atomic variables. If you want to know why fences were designed this way, please add another question.

Answer (score 2):

Ever since C++11 we have had a set of standard classes for exact same use case. `std::optional` is not fit and adhoc solutions are not needed. Simply define a [`std::promise`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) that the single shot producer is about to fullfil, and pass the corresponding [`std::shared_future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future) to the consumers:

```
std::promise<int> pr;
std::shared_future<int> fut {pr.get_future()};


std::jthread consumer1 {[&fut]{
     int x=fut.get();//wait on fut
}};

std::jthread consumer2 {[&fut]{
     while(!fut.valid())
           this_thread::yield();
     int y=fut.get();//instantly read fut
}};

//one-time producer:
pr.set_value(0);
```

Comment: Hah, that is actually the reason for the question.  I am implementing my own version of future/promise to better control thread scheduling and add continuations (and not have the dtor wait if the result isn't available), and the future's result was being stored as an optional.  I also had an atomic_bool for a hasCompleted member variable and was wondering if there was a way to get around it.  Doesn't look like it unless I re-implement parts of optional.

Comment: You could have written it in the OP and saved me the effort. We are all copy+pasters, you know! We don't like keyboard punching 

Comment: Ah my bad sorry :).  I figured if I put that there I'd get a few people focusing on why I'm re-implementing futures instead of what I actually wanted to know.